# EFS mount on an EC2 instance (Ubuntu Server 22.04) changes ownership of directories

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, amazon-efs

I have an EC2 instance running Ubuntu 22.04 Server.
I have EFS fs, that holds users home directories.
EFS is mounted:

```
$ cat /etc/fstab
LABEL=cloudimg-rootfs   /    ext4   discard,errors=remount-ro   0 1
LABEL=UEFI  /boot/efi   vfat    umask=0077  0 1
fs-00000000000000.efs.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com:/ /home nfs4 nfsvers=4.1,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,hard,timeo=600,retrans=2,nodev 0 0

$ mount | grep home
fs-00000000000000.efs.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com:/ on /home type nfs4 (rw,nodev,relatime,vers=4.1,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,namlen=255,hard,proto=tcp,timeo=600,retrans=2,sec=sys,clientaddr=10.x.x.x,local_lock=none,addr=10.x.x.x)
```

If I run `chown -R user1: /home/customer/user1` it changes the ownership of the directory correctly, but the owner is soon (within minutes) changed to some userid >5000 (each directory gets different owner id).
The users are created on the system and have ids 10xx.
There are no users with id >5000 on that system.
This situation started, when we've switched from Amazon Linux 2 to Ubuntu Linux 22.04.

Interesting thing is that ownership is not reverted all across the board, but sort-of randomly:

```
$ ll
total 60
drwxr-xr-x 15 root      6144 Dec  9  2022 ./
drwxr-xr-x  9 root      6144 Jun 30 13:55 ../
drwxr-x---  3 qwe       6144 Jun 29 23:55 qwe/
drwxr-x---  3 asd       6144 Jun 29 23:55 asd/
drwxr-x---  3 zxc       6144 Jun 29 23:55 zxc/
drwxr-x---  3 cvb       6144 Jun 29 23:55 cvb/
drwxr-x---  3 tyu       6144 Jun 29 23:55 tyu/
drwxr-x---  5 ghj       6144 Jun 30 09:03 ghj/
drwxr-x---  3 bnm       6144 Jun 29 23:55 bnm/
drwxr-x---  3 xcv       6144 Jun 29 23:55 xcv/


$ ll
total 60
drwxr-xr-x 15 root     6144 Dec  9  2022 ./
drwxr-xr-x  9 root     6144 Jun 30 14:00 ../
drwxr-x---  3     5103 6144 Jun 29 23:55 qwe/
drwxr-x---  3     5107 6144 Jun 29 23:55 asd/
drwxr-x---  3 zxc      6144 Jun 29 23:55 zxc/
drwxr-x---  3     5106 6144 Jun 29 23:55 cvb/
drwxr-x---  5     5101 6144 Jun 30 23:55 tyu/
drwxr-x---  3 ghj      6144 Jun 29 09:03 ghj/
drwxr-x---  3     5105 6144 Jun 29 23:55 bnm/
drwxr-x---  3 xcv      6144 Jun 29 23:55 xcv/
```

I would like to keep once changed ownership of thiose folders.

I don't see anything in logs that seems relevant.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to fix the issue.

The EFS is mounted at `/home`.

Then there are directories with home dirs for users, like this:

```
$ tree -L 2 /home
.
|-- customerX
|   |-- 111
|   |-- 222
|   |-- 333
|   |-- 444
|   `-- 555
`-- customer
    |-- qwe
    |-- asd
    |-- zxc
    |-- cvb
    |-- tyu
    |-- ghj
    |-- bnm
    `-- xcv
```

I've noticed that home dirs in `/home/customerX` didn't have this issue.
I remembered, that the only difference is that I created a directory `customerX` and then moved user dirs to it, while `customer` was not changed.

So, I created `/home/customerX_new` and moved the home dirs there and the issue is gone.

I guess the problem was how nfs/EFS handles user ownership, but I still don't know what was causing it.

Old and new directories seem to be almost the same:

```
$ stat customerX_new
  File: customerX_new
  Size: 6144        Blocks: 8          IO Block: 1048576 directory
Device: 2bh/43d Inode: 6142551759832195537  Links: 15
Access: (0755/drwxr-xr-x)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2023-06-30 14:17:02.063000000 +0000
Modify: 2023-06-30 14:17:02.063000000 +0000
Change: 2023-06-30 14:17:02.063000000 +0000
 Birth: -

$ stat customerX
  File: customerX
  Size: 6144        Blocks: 8          IO Block: 1048576 directory
Device: 2bh/43d Inode: 7215734139597387765  Links: 2
Access: (0755/drwxr-xr-x)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2023-06-30 14:17:02.063000000 +0000
Modify: 2023-06-30 14:17:02.063000000 +0000
Change: 2023-06-30 14:17:02.063000000 +0000
 Birth: -
```